# My predictions with my train dataset are good but the test one are inverted

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, k-means

For my studies, I have to do a fake bills detector with Python. I have to create a model using linear regression and one model using kmeans in order to predict if the bill is true or false . I have no problems with the one using linear regression but the one using kmeans is giving me some troubles.

I used this model to get my predictions :

```
model_kmean = KMeans(n_clusters = 2) #fake bills (0) and true bills (1)
train_pred_kmean = model_kmean.fit_predict(X_train)
```

I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJIm9.png) with my train dataset which is good as you can see True are predicted with 1 and False with 0. However, when I run my model with my test dataset, I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZebH.png) in which 1 and 0 in the predicted columns are inverted.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and knows a way to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you using to get predictions for the test dataset?

Comment: Hi, I am using this code : test_pred_kmean = model_kmean.fit_predict(X_test)

Comment: Right, so `fit_predict` means you are **re**training the model with the test data.  If you want to use the results of the training to classify the test data, then it's `predict` rather than `fit_predict`.

Comment: One more note: KMeans has grouped the training set into two clusters called 0 and 1, but it's purely coincidence that cluster 0 happens to be the fake bills and that cluster 1 is the true bills.  (KMeans doesn't see your `y_train`, only your `x_train`, so it has no idea what 1 and 0 in the `y_train` column mean.)  However, if your model is working, then if you use `fit_predict` to train and `predict` to predict for the test set, then you should get cluster 0 for the test set to correspond to cluster 0 for the training set, and the same for cluster 1.

Comment: You are a life saver it's all working fine now. also thanks for the infos